# Changing Magento page_layout attribute on products?

Tags: php, database, magento, e-commerce

I have a Magento store with several thousand products, and a subset of them have the "page_layout" attribute set to something other than "no update".  Even though the layout is set to 1 column inside catalog.xml, the layout displayed corresponds to the value on the "page_layout" attribute.

I'd like to programatically change this attribute for every product at once.  So far, I've had luck getting the value of this attribute for a product like this:

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $code = 'page_layout';

    if ($attributeCode == $code) 
    {
        $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        echo $attributeCode . '-' . $label . '-' . $value;
    }
}
```

Now that I have narrowed in on the correct attribute, I'd like to set it.  I'm not having much luck though so far, any experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried $product->setPageLayout(null);
Edit: Afterwards $product->save(), of course.

Answer (score 0):

The possible values for page_layout in a stock magento instance are:

- null
- empty
- two_columns_left
- two_columns_right
- three_columns

Using 'two_columns_left' as an example, to set this value to every single product in the site:

```
$pageLayout = 'two_columns_left';
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setDataToAll('page_layout', $pageLayout)
    ->save()
;
```

Since you have so many products this is most likely going to take a while to run.  To speed things up a little you can change the indexing mode.  Either via admin or directly in your code:

```
$processCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
foreach ($processCollection as $process) {
    $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)
        ->save();
}
```

To change back afterwords:

```
$process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)
    ->save();
```